# Stringstream : non-digit string into an long long gives weird results

Tags: c++, string

I have the following little code :

```
stringstream s; long long n;

n = 1; s << "a";

s >> n;
```

I would expect n would keep the value 1, since you cannot insert a char ("a") into a long long, but n gets the value 0 actually.

Can you tell me why it happens and is there a way I can keep the original value of n ?

Answer (score 0):

Which C++ standard are you compiling with?

< C++11

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set.

>= C++11

> If extraction fails, **zero is written to value** and failbit is set. If extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, std::numeric_limits::max() or std::numeric_limits::min() is written and failbit flag is set.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: I typed gcc --version in the terminal and got the answer of 

gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704

Can you tell me if it's C++11 and above or lower?

Comment: Yikes, almost 10 years old.  Looks like 4.1 doesn't have any c++11 support, so you're using c++98.  (Normally, you would have to add a compile option like '-std=c++11' to use a certain standard, but obviously that won't work if your compiler is too old.)